Handle label feature in TFX in different environments
I'm new in MLOps and trying to figure out how to work with label feature in data. I read that for the uniformity of the data it is necessary to use the same schema for both the training and validation sets.
My question is: How can I mark the label as optional for the validation set? If I received data from users that will not have a label feature, how do I compare the schemas of the new data (without label) with the original schema that contains the label by example_validator?
I know that it can be done by tfdv.get_feature(schema, 'labels').not_in_environment.append('SERVING'), but as far as I know it is not solution for production pipeline.
Another thoughts: using preprocessing function in Transform delete label feature from validation set, but I  don't really understand how context.pipeline.stage works. Example:
if tft.TFTRuntimeContext().context.pipeline.stage == 'train':
    #transform label for training set
else:#for validation set delete label column
    pass

Thanks!
I tried handle this by preprocessing function, but I need to compare schemas from original data and data from user for prediction (without label) BEFORE making transformation. So, this cause error in example_validator.
All way is: ExampleGen - StatisticGen- SchemaGen - ExampleValidator - Transform - (and stage for model).

Conceptually, the validation dataset is used to check how well your model is doing on "unseen" data.  As such, you do need the label in the validation dataset.  And also the test dataset.  Where you won't have the label is at serving time.  Also, when I think of schema, I think input validation.  I'm usually not transforming the label.  tfdv does provide the ability to define environments in which the schema is applicable, and you can specify that a label is not required in the SERVING environment.  Something like tfdv.get_feature(schema, LABEL_NAME).not_in_environment.append('SERVING')
